# Identify a scalar, a list

Tags: list-manipulation, symbolic, assumptions, machine-learning

I have a symbolic scalar `m2` and a symbolic list (representing a 3x3 matrix) `A`. I want a function which does something like:

```
In= function[m2]==Scalar
Out= True
In= function[m2]==List
Out= False

In= function[A]==Scalar
Out= False
In= function[A]==List
Out= True
```

So far I tried doing:

```
In= Assuming[Element[m2, Reals], Head[m2]]
Out= Symbol
```

Out is not what I want! Thank you for you help.

Comment: check out `MatrixQ`

Comment: This sounds like a weird request. I wonder if maybe you might be asking the wrong question. What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: I have a list of symbolic variables `{m2,A,B,C,x,gamma}` for example. I need to go through the list and identify which are scalars, which are matrices (lists). In `$Assumptions` I indicated that `Element[m2|x|gamma,Reals]` and `Element[A|B|C,Matrices[{3,3}]]`. For @chuy MatrixQ does not work, `Assuming[Element[A, Matrices[{3, 3}]], 
 MatrixQ[A]]` gives back `False.`

Comment: @george2079 Sorry I edited the post. In mathematica I have m2 as m_2 (2 as a subscript). Forgot to edit the copy-paste.

Comment: I'm afraid that assumptions don't quite work the way you envision: for instance, `Assuming` won't "cast" a variable to a certain "type". They are more like a note on the margin of the computation, if you will. If the symbol you are using has not been assigned to anything beforehand, it will still be just a `Symbol`, even after the assumption.

Comment: @MarcoB Then what should I do?I like george2079 response, but I'm wondering if a built-in functionality exists.

Comment: See, that's where I think the misunderstanding might lie: such a functionality doesn't exist because it is typically *not needed*. **Why** do you need to know whether a variable is a scalar or a matrix? What will you do with that knowledge?

Comment: @MarcoB I need it because I have to do convert an symbolic algebraic expression into (vector transposed)*(matrix)*(vector). Sometimes a term in the (matrix) will be a scalar, in which case I need to multiply it by a 3x3 identity matrix. I thus need to find out when a term is just a scalar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to track things for your own usage you could do something simple like this:

```
lists = {a, b, c};
scalars = {p, q, r};
function[sym_] := Which[
                  MemberQ[lists, sym], "list",
                  MemberQ[scalars, sym], "scalar",
                        True, Head[sym]]
function /@ {a, p, 0}
```

> {"list", "scalar", Integer}

You *could* try working with this...

```
$Assumptions = {Element[a | b | c, Matrices[{3, 3}]], Element[p | q, foo]}

TrueQ@Simplify[Element[a, Matrices[{3, 3}]]]
TrueQ@Simplify[Element[r, Matrices[{3, 3}]]]
TrueQ@Simplify[Element[p, foo]]
TrueQ@Simplify[Element[r, foo]]
```

> True False True False

That seems like it might be at least confusing, as you know intrinsics like `MatrixQ`,`NumberQ`, etc wont make use of it.

Comment: I'd be careful about using `C`, since it's a built in symbol ([docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/C.html)).

Comment: good call, shouldnt have used CAPS at all..

Answer (score 1):

If you think you will run into that ambiguity a lot you might want to define a function to carry out your calculation:

```
Clear[matrixmult]
matrixmult[m_?MatrixQ, v_?VectorQ] := v.m.v
matrixmult[m_?NumberQ, v_?VectorQ] := v.(m IdentityMatrix[3]).v
```

I used two conditional definitions: the correct definitions will be picked depending on the type of the arguments with which it is called.

So then as an example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
num = RandomReal[];
mat = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}];
vec = RandomReal[1, 3];

matrixmult[num, vec]
matrixmult[mat, vec]

(*Out:
0.640964
0.665124
*)
```

Comment: I don't know if the OP noticed, but in fact, `m v.v` suffices in the scalar case.

Comment: I think this misses the point, as I understand he is working with symbols that have not actually been defined as lists/matrices. @SpaceVoyager might want to supply some example to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

### The Need

I found a solution for the problem, but first since people here asked why would there be a need I'll elaborate about my need.

In my case I defined and inner product which is supposed to act both on vectors and scalars (scalars are just vectors with unit length). Since I wanted the definition to be general for other cases as well, I didn't want to have separate definition for vectors and scalars.

I defined it using `Inner` for the "vector" case. However, when trying to use it on scalars I got:

> Inner::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 2 in Inner

### The Concept

It seems that `ArrayDepth` is able to discern the depth of an object quite well, except for one case when there's a scalar value, which contains arithmetic such as `1+x`. In such a case we get the same result as for a vector, or even for an ill defined object:

```
ArrayDepth[1]
ArrayDepth[x + Sqrt[2 + v]]
ArrayDepth[{1 + v, 1}]
ArrayDepth[{{1}, {1, 2}}]

(*Out:
0
1
1
1
*)
```

We get the same result for the scalar and the vector. However this case can easily be dealt with, because `ListQ` can recognize the scalars correctly:

```
ListQ[1]
ListQ[x + Sqrt[2 + v]]
ListQ[{1 + v, 1}]
ListQ[{{1}, {1, 2}}]

(*Out:
False
False
True
True
*)
```

### The Solution

Hence we can define two functions as a solution. The first lighter solution will be to define a `ScalarQ` function of our own:

```
ScalarQ[object_] := (! ListQ[object] && ArrayDepth[object] == 1) || ArrayDepth[object] == 0
```

This solution gives this:

```
ScalarQ[1]
ScalarQ[x + Sqrt[2 + v]]
ScalarQ[{1 + v, 1}]
ScalarQ[{{1}, {1, 2}}]
```

> True
>
> True
>
> False
>
> False

The second solution will generally identify math objects:

```
MathDimensions::unknown_dimensions = "There was a problem evaluating `1` dimensions."
MathDimensions[object_] := Which[
  Length[Dimensions[object]] >= 3, "Higher Order Tensor",
  MatrixQ[object], "Matrix",
  VectorQ[object], "Vector",
  (! ListQ[object] && ArrayDepth[object] == 1) || ArrayDepth[object] == 0, "Scalar",
  True, Message[MathDimensions::unknown_dimensions, object]; "None"
  ]
```

Which will give us:

```
MathDimensions[1]
MathDimensions[x + Sqrt[2 + v]]
MathDimensions[{1 + v, 1}]
MathDimensions[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]
MathDimensions[{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}]
MathDimensions[{{1}, {1, 2}}]
```

> Scalar
>
> Scalar
>
> Vector
>
> Matrix
>
> Higher Order Tensor
>
> MathDimensions::unknown_dimensions: There was a problem evaluating {{1},{1,2}} dimensions.
>
> None